# Can you use a smaller font?

Tags: support, formatting, font

I am about to ask a question on math.stackexchange, which requires me to talk a little bit about my representation.

For example I include an AMScd picture, which does not look exactly how it is supposed to look like, since I do not know better, so I explain it verbally.

For the sake of readability of my question (and all those remarks are a little annoying), I would like to include them as a smaller font, to showcase, that they are not really important.

I already visited the help center and a meta.stackexchange thread on html.
It seems like, that you can not use smaller fonts here.

Is there a way to include smaller text?

Else I might solve it like this:

```
blablablalbbllalbblablablalbbllalbblablablalbbllalbblablablalbbllalbblablablalbbllalbblablablalbbllalbblablablalbbllalbblablablalbbllalbblablablalbbllalbblablablalbbllalb
```

So it does not take to much space, but still looks awful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

As suggested in other posts about this issue, you can use `<sup>` or `<sub>`. It is probably not optimal, but at least doable within the limitations of the software. See: [How do I use a small font size in questions and answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/26756) You can also support a related feature requests [Allow the `<small>` tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40035) and [Markdown extension for really small tiny text?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53800)

<sup>So when I occasionally have some less important text and I want to stress visually that it is less important, I simply put it between `<sup>` and `</sup>`. It is definitely not ideal, the text looks a bit unusual - but at least it is visibly smaller and visually distinguished from the rest of the text.</sup>